# How to come out of recusion

Tags: sql, recursion, common-table-expression, subset-sum

In reference to [this](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/10/26/how-to-find-the-closest-subset-sum-with-sql/) blog post, can you please let me know is there a way to modify our approach so that if we find a perfect match, we’ll drop out and not calculate the remaining possibilities?

Comment: It looks like it does the comparison of all computed values `sum` AFTER all of the recursion is complete. There is no context for comparison while performing the recursion (as I understand it). The basic fact of the matter is, the amount of potential combinations of "subsets" to find potential sums grows exponentially as your data grows. This question has 10 items. Doing this on a list of just a few hundred could yield hundreds of trillions of potential sum subsets. It's just not feasible in any system and doing this for a large set in SQL is ridiculous.

Comment: Thanks, Nevill! I tried the above solution in SQL using CTE for 20 records and it completed in 3 minutes. but when I increased from 20 to 25, it took 56 minutes. do you know what could be the best implementation of this problem? we have a requirement of matching customer payment(receipt) to all the open invoices of the customer. if any combination of the open invoice is matching with the payment, we need to apply. do you have any other pointers that could help us in this?

Comment: That's the problem. Permutations increase dramatically as you add more samples. 25 is probably pushing it. There are 1022 possible combinations of 10 numbers so getting all of them is pretty simple work and probably runs in seconds. For 20 it's `263950`. Some work but not terrible. At `25` it's `1807781` combinations. It's getting serious. That is a lot of iterations. At `100` it's like `1.26 * 10^30`. My math may be off, but it's stupid huge. Now... that number is cut down dramatically if you limit the recursion once you go over the sum you are seeking. If you are seeking many sums though...

Comment: ... you could (Conceivably) limit your recursion to the max(receipt total) and pretty drastically cut that down. But... it's still going to be a monster. Personally if I was handed this task I would suggest that the company cut it's losses and write it off as stitching that paper trail back together is going to be more work than it's worth (if it's even possible).

Comment: That's a good idea. let me try if I can limit the recursion to the receipt total. Another thing is that we will not have 100's of open invoices. If I can tune the solution for 40, that will work.